# Difference in allocation policy between implementations of STL?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, stl, mingw-w64

I just discovered that the default allocator for `basic_string<char>` from the STL in the implementation of **GCC 4.9** (using MinGW-w64) does not use the global `operator new()` but maybe directly `malloc`, but the implementation in **MSVC 11** (VS 2012) uses it.

Also tried gcc 4.4.6 under CentOS and there the operator was called as expected.

Why is there such a difference and isn't the MSVC approach the correct way? I would like to be able to track every allocation done by the STL by just providing my own `operator new()`.

This is my test code:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct MallocAllocator
{
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef T value_type;

    pointer allocate(size_type n, const void* = 0) {
        cout << "Custom: " << sizeof(value_type) * n << endl;
        return static_cast<pointer>(malloc(sizeof(value_type) * n));
    }

    void deallocate(pointer ptr, size_type) {
        free(ptr);
    }

    // boilerplate follows
    MallocAllocator() {}

    MallocAllocator(const MallocAllocator&) {}

    size_type max_size () const throw() { return std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(T); }

    template <typename Other>
    MallocAllocator(const MallocAllocator<Other>&) {}

    MallocAllocator& operator=(const MallocAllocator&) { return *this; }

    template <class Other>
    MallocAllocator& operator=(const MallocAllocator<Other>&) { return *this; }

    template <typename Other>
    struct rebind { typedef MallocAllocator<Other> other; };

    pointer address(reference ref) const {
        return &ref;
    }

    const_pointer address(const_reference ref) const {
        return &ref;
    }

    void construct(pointer ptr, const value_type& val) {
        ::new(ptr) value_type(val);
    }

    void destroy(pointer ptr) {
        ptr->~value_type();
    }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator==(const MallocAllocator<T>&, const MallocAllocator<U>&) {
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator!=(const MallocAllocator<T>& a, const MallocAllocator<U>& b) {
    return !(a == b);
}

void *operator new(size_t s) {
    cout << "Global: " << s << endl;
    return (void*)malloc(s);
}

void *operator new[](size_t s) {
    cout << "Global: " << s << endl;
    return (void*)malloc(s);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, MallocAllocator<char> > s;
    basic_string<char> s;
    s = "dfasdf";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += ".";
    s += "dfasdfsdfasfsdfasdfsdfasfsdfasdfsdfasfsdfasdfsdfasfsdfasdfsdfasfsdfasdfsdfasfsdfasdfsdfasfsdfasdfsdfasfsdfasdfsdfasfs";

    cout << s << endl;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    system("pause");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

With GCC from MinGW-w64: When I use the custom allocator, I see the allocations. When I do not use it, I see nothing.

Comment: FWIW - it does use the global new from GCC 4.8.1 - see [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Akj19D) - must be a recent change.  Makes me wonder if it's trying to `realloc` instead of new/copy/delete every time....

Comment: I just tried with **gcc 4.8.1** from **MinGW-w64** and again it did not work. But from a normal gcc under linux (any version) it works as desired.

Comment: @blender. It may be the mingw-w64 runtime in the shared dll that causes this error. I'll pick this up again on Monday and try some more combinations of static and shared linkage etc. I think they are both supported in the mingw-build I have.

Comment: @blender, I've run some more tests, it looks like it is that the `std::string` is exported from the runtime (building with `--static` gives the expected behaviour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may just be a bug in the mingw-w64 runtime or "mingw-builds"...

It is possible that the runtime being used in the "mingw-builds" build has exported of the use of `std::string` with the default allocators from a pre-built dll (I have not been able to confirm this, it is possibly the mingw-w64 runtime itself), MSVC did something similar in the past (although I wouldn't know if this caused a similar error).

Some combinations I've tried:

- The "mingw-builds" build using a `vector` and the overridden `operator new` is used as expected.
- Building the executable (mingw-builds) with a static binding (`--static`) to the runtime works as expected (for `string` and `vector`).
- The "nuwen" build and that works as expected for both `string` and `vector`.
- VS2013 also calls the overridden `operator new` was used with the `std::allocator` (with and without the `/MD` option).
- VS2008 (with `/MD`) produces the unexpected output (`std::string` is exported from the runtime dll, IIRC).

From what I can make out the `std::string` is exported from "libstdc++-6.dll" and so the binding to `::operator new` etc. is probably already fixed (as you now know) in the binary for the `string` allocations.

A simple change to the allocator;

```
template <class C>
struct myallocator : std::allocator<C> {
};
```

Allows the overridden global `operator new` to work as expect with the "mingw-builds". You have already noted this with you full custom allocator, but the simple derivation here supports the notion that the "default" string class is possibly being sourced from a dll.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
// replacement of a minimal set of functions:
void* operator new(std::size_t sz) {
    std::printf("global op new called, size = %d\n",sz);
    return std::malloc(sz);
}
void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept
{
    std::puts("global op delete called");
    std::free(ptr);
}
template <class C>
struct myallocator : std::allocator<C> {
};
int main() {
     using namespace std;

     vector<int> def;
     def.resize(100000);

     basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, myallocator<char>> abc;
     abc.resize(100000);
}
```

Command lines

```
cl /EHsc file.cpp
cl /EHsc /MD file.cpp
g++ --std=c++11 file.cpp
g++ --static --std=c++11 file.cpp
```

Comment: Link to the mingw-w64 bug report that is already filed by someone :) http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/422/

Answer (score 1):

n3376 20.6.9.2

> `pointer allocate(size_type n, allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0);`
>
> Remark: **the storage is obtained by calling ::operator new(std::size_t)**
>   (18.6.1), but it is unspec- ified when or how often this function is
>   called. The use of hint is unspecified, but intended as an aid to
>   locality if an implementation so desires.

Are you sure, that operator new is not called?

Answer (score 0):

The gcc `basic_string` class does have a `allocator` argument for the template. This means that you could, with one small change (to the `stringfwd.h`), update `std::string` to use a different allocation method, including one that uses `new`.

Where it says:

```
typedef basic_string<char>    string;
```

change it to:

```
typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, my_allocator>    string;
```

Although I would expect that you may just see that the implementation is optimised and uses some internal storage for small strings - once you need a large enough string, it should use `new` for the allocation, I expect.

Comment: I tried with up to 138 chars in a string (with concatenations) and still no call to ```operator new()```

Comment: If I use a custom allocator I get a few calls to allocate(). Im guessing I should get the same number of calls to ```operator new()``` when not using a custom allocator.

Comment: Yes, same number of calls to operator new(), assuming the default allocator does indeed use `new`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I can be wrong, but implementation of `operator new()` on Windows directly or indirectly calls `malloc()`, which calls functions such `VirtualAlloc` for real memory allocation by OS. There are no other ways for memory allocation and you may be calm about this.